# Finding Last Row With Data With Formatted Cells Below

Tags: excel, vba

I need to identify, (by highlighting), when there is data missing from a certain column. In other words, I have a column of data specifying a country. Above this column there are blanks and below this column there are blanks. The topmost row of the data stays the same (the data always starts at row 4), but the bottom is variable. Also, due to the way this data is output, there seems to be 3 or so rows of blank but formatted cells at the bottom of the table which excel recognizes as 'used'. Here is my code thus far:

```
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

LastRowCountry = .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

End With
```

---

The Piece of code that is specific to my goal is:

```
'Search for blank Geo tags

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

If IsEmpty(Cells(LastRowCountry, "H")) = True Then

     'Highlight Columns

        With Range(Cells(4, "H"), Cells(LastRow, "H")).Interior

          .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic

          .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2

          .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314

          .PatternTintAndShade = 0

        End With

       End If

         End With
```

---

In this form it fails to recognize any blanks in the column and never highlights.  Before this I preceded the code with:

```
With ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)

LastRow = .Row

LastCol = .Column

End With
```

which always highlighted the column (I assume because it was detecting the blank but formatted cells hanging off the bottom of the table. Thanks in advance to anyone who takes this on.

Steve

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want.  Your current code finds the last populated cell in column `H`, then if that cell is empty highlights the whole column.  So it will never highlight because by definition the last populated cell isn't empty (unless you use a faulty method of determining it!)  Do you want to search for blanks *within* the column as well/instead?

Comment: Btw, you are right - `.Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` is a good way to find the last non-empty cell; and `xlLastCell` (and `UsedRange`) is unreliable.

Comment: Sorry for my ambiguity. Let's say my table has 200 rows of data starting on row 5 (the preceding cells are blank) in column H. The last possible row for data is row 205 (after row 205 the cells are blank but formatted). I need this code to go in identify that the last row is 'row 205' and then search through all 200 "data possible" rows (5-205) in column H for blanks. If any one of those 200 cells is blank, I want to have the column highlighted. Perhaps I need to identify the last used row in the sheet to protect against a blank in r205. Does that clarify my question? Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried this here and it works

```
Sub CheckForEmptyCells(Byref sh as Worksheet, ByRef col as string)
  Dim lastR&
  lastR = sh.Range(col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Dim r As Range: Set r = Range(col & "5:" & col & lastR)
  If Not r.Find("") Is Nothing Then
     With r.Interior
          .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
          .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
          .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
          .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
  End If
End Sub
```

Note: this routine checks only if the given column has empty cells in between its own first and last cells. If the goal is to check the whole column (last cell of the column might itself be empty), then you should use instead: `lastR = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: This is likely my fault, but I'm having trouble getting this code to run. I can't seem to insert it into my larger macro and when I try to run it on its own, Excel doesn't recognize it. Could you briefly explain what is going on with the value within the parentheses after the subroutine name? Thanks.

Comment: I made the subroutine flexible so that you can run it on any worksheet and any column in that worksheet (the two parameters). Hence, to call it correctly as you wanted in your question, just call it this way from any macro: *CheckForEmptyCells ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet, "H"*

Comment: - Yes it does thanks. Really cool solution. For anyone else in my boat, Insert the subroutine provided by A.S.H. above at the bottom of your macro. Then, insert the  CheckForEmptyCells ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet, "Col#" in the location that you want to carry out the search.

Comment: Glad it helped :). Please check the answered button.